# Is this the wrong way to make a method async?

Tags: c#, async-await

I want a method like this:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

But because there is no AWAIT I get a warning that it will run synchronously. That was not my intent. My intent was to run async. So, I do this:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

This works. But is this cheating or something?

Comment: *Why* do you want to make it `async`? Making a method `async` probably doesn't mean what you think it means. It certainly doesn't mean the method will run concurrently.

Comment: Yeah, it means what I think it means. I appreciate the assumption, however. I'm just dealing with methods that do not support await.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make the method run asynchronously, you'd typically write it like:

```
public Task DoSomething()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoSomethingElse());
}
```

This will cause the TPL to schedule your method to run (on a background thread), and allow the caller to use `await` when they call your method if they need to use the async/await support.

Your current code doesn't actually cause this to run asynchronously - it causes the method to run and return immediately, but then schedule the `DoSomethingElse()` to occur on the same synchronization context in which you're currently running.  This means that, if you call your method on a UI thread, you'll immediately continue your previous code, and not block the UI *right then*, but will still block it later when the context execute the `DoSomethingElse()` call.

This is, of course, assuming that `DoSomethingElse()` is not itself an asynchronous method.  If it's defined as `Task DoSomethingElse()`, you could just write:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    // other code as needed
    await DoSomethingElse();
    // other code as needed
}
```

Comment: So, to add to the answer, this means that to run a method that is synchronous by design, you need to start a new `Task` as shown above. The `async` and `await` keywords are designed to help you deal with `Task`s! Rather than using `Task.ContinueWith` all the time, you can just write your code as normal with await.

Comment: +1. Also, I would *recommend* Reed's second example: change both `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` to `async` methods (unless `DoSomethingElse` actually does computational work, in which case you do want to run it on the thread pool using `StartNew` or `Task.Run`).

Comment: One other minor point: notice how Reed's methods return `Task`. That is the Correct Way To Do It. Don't use `async void` unless the methods are event handlers.

Comment: @StephenCleary Which kind of brings up something else - if there is not "other code as needed" in that second example, you could just use: `public Task DoSomething() { return DoSomethingElse(); }` - No need for async/await at all if the wrapped method is already async.